# symfony 2 form input fields are not rendered

Tags: php, forms, symfony, templates, twig

I'm trying to create simple form but for some reason input fields are not rendered. The source code shows that the open and close tag of form are rendered but not the input fields itself.

Here is the code

```
namespace SDProjectBundle\Forms;


use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class UserForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function formBuilder(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', 'text')
                ->add('password', 'password')
                ->add('Send', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_users';
    }
}
```

```
namespace SDProjectBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use SDProjectBundle\Forms\UserForm;
use SDProjectBundle\Entity\User;


class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserForm(), new User());

        return $this->render('SDProjectBundle:Users:add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

add.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change the form getname method to something else?

Comment: Nothing. Blank page again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You implements the wrong method in the form class: you need to implements the *`buildForm`* method of your custom form type.

Practically, in the `UserForm` class, you need to put this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
```

instead of

```
public function formBuilder(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render the form component try with

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

instead of

```
{{ form_label(form) }}
```

If you want to render only the label of the field you need to specify the field as:

```
{{ form_label(form.email) }}
```

**A complete manually rendered version of your form can be:**

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    <div>
        {{ form_label(form.email) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ form_label(form. password) }}
        {{ form_errors(form. password) }}
        {{ form_widget(form. password) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form. Send) }}
    </div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: form_label is a typo. In the code it's actual form_widget and as mentioned I get  blank page but with form tags. When I try with  form_widget(form.email) I get an error saying 
Method "email" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist

Comment: hi @Vodokan, very strange... which version of the framework are you using? I will try to replicate your scenario

Comment: Symfony version 2.7.3 - app/dev/debug

Comment: Hi @Vodokan  i replicate your problem and post my solutions in another answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your TWIG:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```